# How does Apple's Preview.app identify alpha background?

Tags: ios, graphics

Apple's Preview.app allows me to identify each area of an image with an alpha channel, and remove them.

I would like to know a) how this is done, b), if this is possible in iOS, and c) can I replace background elements and instead of removing them, to do something else, for example, change their color.

Swift or Obj-C examples are fine, or please let me know the appropriate framework/API that I should study, and I'll look from there.

Many thanks

Comment: There is noting built in that will do this for you. You'd have to build your own image processing. A good place to start would be the [Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip!